# Nginx + PHP-FPM Permission denied for user home dir

Tags: php, linux, nginx, permissions

PHP-FPM config

```
user = www-data
group = www-data

listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
```

Nginx config

```
user www-data;
```

And host config is

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    root /home/SITENAME/www;
    index index.php;

    server_name SITENAME.com www.SITENAME.com;
    include snippets/ssl-SITENAME.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    access_log /home/SITENAME/logs/access.log combined;
    error_log /home/SITENAME/logs/error.log warn;

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    expires 86400s;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";

    location ~* ^.+\.(css|js)$ {
        rewrite ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(css|js)$ $1.$3 last;
        expires 31536000s;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
    }

    location ~* \.(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|ogv|otf|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|t?gz|tif|tiff|ttf|wav|webm|wma|woff|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$ {
        expires 31536000s;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
    }
}
```

User sitename is in a group www-data and user www-data is in a group user, but i still cant write in home directory, how to fix that?
Chown user home dir to www-data is not solution, like is not solution using 777.

Comment: Just for clarity, post the output of the following commands: `# id www-data`, `# stat /home/SITENAME/www`.

Comment: `uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data),1003(SITENAME)`

Comment: ```stat /home/SITENAME/www
  File: '/home/SITENAME/www'
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 9650b621h/2521871905d   Inode: 131164      Links: 6
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1003/  SITENAME)   Gid: ( 1003/  SITENAME)
Access: 2018-08-01 04:46:11.143075430 -0400
Modify: 2018-08-01 04:43:17.506400480 -0400
Change: 2018-08-01 04:43:17.506400480 -0400
 Birth: -```

Comment: Why not add `SITENAME` user to `www-data` group and use `SITENAME` in PHP-FPM configuration?
The current setup goes kinda backward.

Comment: Cuz i have not only one SITENAME